# MySQL: Missing some records in mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, records, mysqlimport

I am importing data into `InnoDB` table with huge number of records. The command mysqlimport says successfully imported as shown below. I am importing the data on an empty table.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqlimport.exe --fields-terminated-by=',' 
--columns="invoice_id,customername,department,city" --local -u root -p invoice11954 "c:\11954\invoice.txt"

Enter password:
invoice11954.invoice: Records: 1540252  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But when I check the count of records in the table invoices, I see only `1534408` records. I have truncated the table and reimported again and again. There is always a mismatch in the record count and difference of records is not always constant.

Is it something to do with my configuration? I have given high values for configuration but still no luck.

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 1024K
net_buffer_length = 16K
read_buffer_size = 512K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1024K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 128M
```

My configuration doesn't have this section `[mysqlimport]`

Can someone help me what's going wrong here.

Comment: Do you think the table contains duplicates?

Comment: try creating the same table with no constraints, and importing to that, see if you get a different record count

Comment: My table doesn't have any referential keys or constants. If there are constraints then the difference should be constant when I import same data again and again. I will add my command and [mysqliimport] section

Comment: dump the table you just imported and diff it against the imported dump to see what rows are supposedly missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you checking the "count of records" in the `invoices` table? Obviously, we're assuming that you're executing a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoice ;
```

And that you aren't relying on the estimated number of rows in `information_schema.tables` to give you a precise count.

---

There's not enough information in the question, in its current form to give an answer for the behavior you are observing. As I noted in my comment, it's not clear whether the table has any unique constraints, of whether you've specified the `--replace` or `--ignore` options, because we don't see the command you are running, the `[mysqlimport]` section of the `my.cnf` file, or how you are checking the number of rows on the table after it's loaded.

Comment: @Vikram: How are you checking the number of rows in the table? What result is returned by `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoice;` ?

Comment: Yes, I am checking the count using `select count(*) from invoices` query

Comment: Ok, Very stupid I am relying on `phpmyadmin` count `Showing rows 0 - 24 (2308731 total, Query took 0.0010 seconds.)` which shows on top. I think this is bug on `phpmyadmin`

Comment: @Vikram: Likely that's documented behavior. If you are doing a "table open" or something like that, based on what you're showing here, it's likely that the tool is running a query `SELECT * FROM invoice LIMIT 0,24` and then reporting the "estimated number of rows" in the table, from `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'invoice' and table_schema = 'invoice11954'`. The value for "rows" there is an optimizer statistic; the optimizer doesn't need an exact count, only a rough estimate.